# How to make gapi authentication work in office-js dialog - error - Not a valid origin for the client

Tags: office-js, google-api-js-client

I have successfully authenticated via my browser using this gapi authentication browser example:

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

When I use the same details via office js dialog, using gapi - it fails with error:

> Error: Not a valid origin for the client: https://localhost:3000 has not been whitelisted for client ID 9999999999999999999999999 Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID.

I have added this url to my google console credentials in both Authorized JavaScript origins
and Authorized Redirect Uris to be sure:

- https://localhost:3000
- http://localhost:3000
- https://localhost:3000/login/login.html

Yet I still get the same error message. I am wondering whether there is something else I need to add to make it work via the excel addin - office js.

This is my code in login.ts

**login.ts**

```js
const { client_id, API_KEY } = process.env;

(() => {
  console.log('before Office.initialize', Office);
  Office.initialize = async () => {

    const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

    const updateSigninStatus = (isSignedIn) => {
      if (isSignedIn) {
        localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "yes");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "no");
      }
    };

    const initClient = () => {
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: client_id,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES
      }).then(function () {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
        
        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      }, (error) => {
 
        // handle error
        Office.context.ui.messageParent( JSON.stringify({ status: 'failure', result: error.details }));
      });
    };

    
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have realised the problem was to do with cache.

1. Ensure using edge browser:

```
npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml edge
```

2. Go to Edge settings - and set - automatically clear cache on close browser

This cleared the cache, and now I have proceeded onto the next problem.
New ticket.